# Greater Average Submatrix

Tags: code-challenge

### Objective

Write a program in any language that reads a matrix from `stdin` in which all columns are space delimited and all rows are newline delimited. The program must output a sub matrix so as that there is no other sub matrix with greater average, this sub matrix' average value, as well as the starting and ending coordinates. Each sub matrix must be at least 2x2. The initial matrix can be an m *x* n matrix where 2 < m < 256 and 2 < n < 512. For each element e, you know that -1000000 < e < 1000000

### Example Inputs

A)

```
1 2 3 4 5 6
7 8 9 10 11 12
13 14 15 16 17 18
```

B)

```
1 1 1
1 1 1
1 1 1
```

### Example Output

A)

```
Sub Matrix:
11 12
17 18
Average of all values:
14.5
Starting Coordinates:
[4,0]
Ending Coordinates:
[5,1]
```

B)

```
Sub Matrix:
1 1
1 1
Average of all values:
1
Starting Coordinates:
[0,0]
Ending Coordinates:
[1,1]
```

### Rules

You may not use any matrix related library provided for your language but you may use lists, arrays, tables, dictionaries and all the operations that can be performed without including / importing anything in your language.

### Scoring

1. You get one point for every additional byte of code.
2. You get one point for every variable you use (even if it's a list).
3. You get one point for every function / method (including lambda / anonymous) you use.
4. The winner is the solution with the fewest points.

Comment: What if there are multiple solutions (like your B example all non-empty submatricies are valid answers.)

Comment: @Zereges This is why the question states that there shouldn't be a sub matrix with greater average. This essentially means that if there are duplicates, any one of them is welcome.

Comment: The required output is somewhat unclear. In the text, it says "must output a sub matrix". But then in the examples, it also shows the average value, and the coordinates of two corners. Is all of this required?

Comment: @RetoKoradi Sorry, answer edited. These are actually required.

Comment: Surely there's always a maximum-average matrix of the smallest allowed size 2x2, since the average of a matrix is the average of its 2x2 submatrices?

Comment: @xnor I'm not sure I understand the question but you're not looking only for 2x2. You have to compare all the 2x2's to all the 2x3's and the 3x2's and the 3x3's etc. I can think of certain cases where a 3x3 can have a greater average than a 2x2.

Comment: Is the submatrix a single contiguous block, or can it be an arbitrary subset of the rows and columns? Apparently the term is ambiguous. I was thinking of the second, but since you mention starting and ending coords, you probably mean the first, in which case the best submatrix indeed might not be 2x2.

Comment: @xnor No, a sub matrix is a rectangle so the first case is true.

Comment: Well, since `avg(a,b) <= max(a,b)`, there will always exist submatrix of size `1x1` which has greatest avg. So the question can be reformulated as `find maximum of following numbers.`

Comment: @Zereges It does say that the submatrix must be at least 2x2.

Comment: @xnor On the theory that there is always a 2x2 that has the maximum average. I don't think that's true. Counter-example: a 3x3 matrix with values ((9 0 9) (0 9 0) (9 0 9)). The average of the whole matrix is 45/9 = 5. Each 2x2 submatrix has the values ((9 0) (0 9)) or ((0 9) (9 0)), which all have an average of 18/4 = 4.5.

Comment: @RetoKoradi Yes, that's true. I had mistakenly understood submatrix to allow a non-contiguous of the rows and columns, where taking the first and last of each would give average 9.

Comment: @DaKnOb What if all arrays/lists available in your language are matrices, and almost every command there is is about manipulating matrices?

Comment: @flawr If you are not including a library and these are built in functions (MatLab comes to mind) then you are free to use them.

Comment: If elements can be negative, is greatest defined as max(abs()) or most +ve?

Comment: @TomCarpenter The greatest is defined as the maximum numerical value. No absolute value is put in place. Between -10 and 2, 2 is the greatest number.

Comment: That's what I figured, just wanted to check.

Comment: Example output A, starting should be 4,1 ending should be 5,2

Answer (score 1):

## MATLAB, 332 + 9 + 7 = 348

The code:

```
v=str2num(input(''));s=size(v);d=[];e={};for m=1:s(1)-1 for n=1:s(2)-1 for o=1:s(1)-m for p=1:s(2)-n q=v(o:m+o,p:n+p);e=[e {q}];d=[d;mean(q(:)) o p o+m p+n];end;end;end;end;[~,m]=max(d(:,1));disp('Sub Matrix:');disp(e{m});fprintf('Average of all values:\n%f\nStarting Coordinates:\n[%d,%d]\nEnding Coordinates:\n[%d,%d]\n',d(m,1:5))
```

And an explanation

```
%Functions used (7):
%    input str2num size mean max disp fprintf
%Variables used (9):
%    v s d e m n o p q

v=str2num(input('')); %Convert to matrix (new lines and spaces are correctly handled by str2num to form dimensions)
s=size(v); %Dimensions of n.
d=[];
e={};
for m=1:s(1)-1
    %Loop through all widths from 2 up to the width of the matrix (-1 to save doing that later)
    for n=1:s(2)-1
        %Loop through all heights from 2 up the the width of the matrix (-1 to save doing that later)
        for o=1:s(1)-m
            for p=1:s(2)-n
                %Extract the sub array
                q=v(o:m+o,p:n+p);
                %Store the sub array in a cell array so we don't have to extract it later.
                e=[e {q}];
                %Append to the list the details (mean and indicies) of this sub array.
                d=[d;mean(q(:)) o p o+m p+n];
            end
        end
    end
end
%Find the index of the sub array with the largest mean
[~,m]=max(d(:,1));
%And print the output
disp('Sub Matrix:');
disp(e{m});
fprintf('Average of all values:\n%f\nStarting Coordinates:\n[%d,%d]\nEnding Coordinates:\n[%d,%d]\n',d(m,1:5))
```

`input` asks for you to enter the matrix. Because MATLAB struggles with new lines, you need to type something like `['1 2 3 4' 10 '5 6 7 8']` Note that the 10 is the new line character. This basically just forms the array exactly as your string would be (the `'` and `[]` are not passed in to the code)

Comment: I'm not a Matlab expert (I only used it like 2-3 times) but is the last semicolon necessary?

Comment: @DaKnOb good point :)

Answer (score 0):

## Matlab, 386 = 366 + 12 + 8

I assumed that we have to make outputs exactly formatted like the output example.

Variables:

```
a,N,r,c,M,i,j,k,l,P,p,n
```

Functions:

```
input,char,str2num,numel,reshape,mean,disp,sprintf
```

Code (added newlines and indenteation for readability):

```matlab
a=input('');
N=char(10);
r=sum(a==N);
a(a==N)=32;
a=str2num(a);
c=numel(a)/r;
a=reshape(a,r,c);
M=-inf;
for i=1:r-1;
    for j=1:c-1;
        for k=i+1:r;
            for l=j+1:c;
                P=a(i:k,j:l);
                p=mean(P(:));
                if p>M(1);
                    M=[p,i,j,k,l];
                    n=P;
                end;    
            end;
        end;
    end;
end;
disp('Sub Matrix:');
disp(n);c='ing Coordinates:\n[%d,%d]\n';
disp(sprintf(['Average of all values\n%d\nStart',c,'End',c],M(1),M(2),M(3),M(4),M(5)))
```

Comment: You can save a variable (```N```) and some code by getting rid of ```N=char(10);``` and simply putting 10 in place of every ```N```